# magento 2 override Magento\Sales\Model\Order.php get method for REST api

Tags: magento2, api, sales-order, rest-api

magento 2 override Magento\Sales\Model\Order.php get method for REST api to add some details.

i am getting an error in di compile

```
Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Custom\\Sales\\Model\\OrderRepository::setShippingAssignments() must be an instance of Custom\\Sales\\Api\\Data\\OrderInterface, instance of Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Interceptor given
```

/rest/V1/order/:orderID

webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/order/:id" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Custom\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" type="Custom\Sales\Model\OrderRepository"/>
<preference for="Custom\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface" type="Custom\Sales\Model\Order"/>
<type name="Custom\Sales\Model\OrderRepository">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="metadata" xsi:type="object">orderMetadata</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<virtualType name="orderMetadata" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Metadata">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="resourceClassName" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order</argument>
        <argument name="modelClassName" xsi:type="string">Custom\Sales\Model\Order</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Custom\Mobileshop\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Mobileshop\Api;

interface OrderRepositoryInterface
{
/**
 * Loads a specified order.
 *
 * @param int $id The order ID.
 * @return \Custom\Mobileshop\Api\Data\OrderInterface Order interface.
 */
public function get($id);   }
```

Custom\Mobileshop\Model\OrderRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Mobileshop\Model;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order as Resource;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Metadata;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterfaceFactory as SearchResultFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory;
use Custom\Mobileshop\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;

/**
 * Repository class for @see OrderInterface
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */class OrderRepository implements \Custom\Mobileshop\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface{
/**
 * @var Metadata
 */
protected $metadata;

/**
 * @var SearchResultFactory
 */
protected $searchResultFactory = null;

/**
 * @var OrderExtensionFactory
 */
private $orderExtensionFactory;

/**
 * @var ShippingAssignmentBuilder
 */
private $shippingAssignmentBuilder;

/**
 * \Custom\Mobileshop\Api\Data\OrderInterface[]
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $registry = [];

/**
 * OrderRepository constructor.
 *
 * @param Metadata $metadata
 * @param SearchResultFactory $searchResultFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Metadata $metadata,
    SearchResultFactory $searchResultFactory
) {
    $this->metadata = $metadata;
}

/**
 * load entity
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @return \Custom\Mobileshop\Api\Data\OrderInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function get($id)
{
    if (!$id) {
        throw new InputException(__('Id required'));
    }
    if (!isset($this->registry[$id])) {
        /** @var \Custom\Mobileshop\Api\Data\OrderInterface $entity */
        $entity = $this->metadata->getNewInstance()->load($id);

        /*$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $entity = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);*/

        if (!$entity->getEntityId()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Requested entity doesn\'t exist'));
        }
        // $this->setShippingAssignments($entity);
        $this->registry[$id] = $entity;
    }
    return $this->registry[$id];
}

}
```

Custom\Mobileshop\Api\Data\OrderInterface.php
Custom\Mobileshop\Model\Order.php